# Probability calculation using De Moivre approximation

Tags: probability

I've encountered this question during homework. (Answer provided)

I understand that I need to use Xm = (m - np)/(root(npq))

And to use F(Xm), while m=179. I don't understand why m=179.5 in this solution.

I know that the Laplace theorem proof uses m+0.5, but I don't understand why it's used here as well

[image]

Answer (score 2):

That extra 0.5 is called the continuity correction. It slightly improves the accuracy of normal approximation of the binomial by treating each nonnegative integer $k$ as if it were the interval $(k-0.5,k+0.5)$. In this case it is treating $180$ as the interval $(179.5,180.5)$.

If you already understand the case of the lower tail (the CDF), just think of this as 1 minus a lower tail.

Comment: Still 1 thing is unclear: 
The de Moivre'a - Laplace theorm includes RANGE (a,b):
P(a - 0.5 <= m <= b+0.5) =  Ø(Xb+0.5) - Ø(Xa - 0.5)

In all of the answers it seems that the range is IGNORED and only a is taken into account.

I can explain it like this: a=180, b = infinity
P( a-0.5 <= m <= b + 0.5) = P(179.5 <= m <= infinity) 
Therefore the complement is 
P( -infinity < m < 179.5) = Ø(179.5) - Ø(-infinity)
and Ø(-infinity) = 0

Does it explain it? Or am I missing something? @JCH

Comment: @JohnSnowTheDeveloper You can simply take the other endpoint to be $\pm \infty$ if you want to just look at the left or right tail instead of a bounded interval.

Answer (score 1):

From  de Moivre'a - Laplace theorem:

$ Pr(X \geq 180 ) = 1 - Pr(X < 180) =1 - Pr\left(Z < \frac{180 -1000\cdot 0,2}{\sqrt{1000\cdot 0,2\cdot (1- 0,2)}}\right)\approx 1-\phi(-1,5811)= \phi(1,5811)\approx 0,9431.$

Comment: Your second $=$ is not an equality. And you haven't included the continuity correction that is the whole point of this question. And you've used lowercase $\phi$ which is usually used for the *density*, not the CDF.